# mustache.php security

Tags: php, mustache

I'm building an app where user is able to enter Mustache markup in textarea and generate output with help of [mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) and class-based context.

Example code:

```
<?php
$m = new Mustache_Engine;
$chris = new Chris;
echo $m->render($CUSTOM_USER_INPUT_TEXT, $chris);
```

Example class context:

```
<?php
class Chris {
    public $name  = "Chris";
    public $value = 10000;
    private $test = '';

    public function taxed_value() {
        return $this->value - ($this->value * 0.4);
    }

    public $in_ca = true;
}
```

My question: is there any chance that user will be able to call some other functions, except `Chris` public methods and properties? (from mustache markup)

Thank you.

Comment: Who is "user"? It's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Shouldn't be able to - there is nothing else in the class for them to be able to pull out?

Comment: @Tomalak User is anyone. Imagine site with textarea where you can enter Mustache template and by clicking submit button it'll generate proper markup.

Comment: @Chris No, it's just this class, it doesn't extend anything.

Comment: I don't think that people will be able to pull out anything other than the name and value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to render user input, provided you carefully control the rendering context. Users only have access to public properties and methods of objects in the rendering context.

Just be careful what you give your users access to. They will be able to call any method on any object they can traverse to. For example, if Chris has a Car, exposed at `Chris::$car`, they can get to it with `{{ chris.car }}`. This means if you use an ActiveRecord style domain model, you should never pass your model objects into the rendering context. Otherwise, a user could call `{{ chris.car.delete }}`.